# Switch focus onclick to dynamically added text input

Tags: jquery, input, focus, onclick, live

Let me preface this question by saying that I'm a jQuery noob - just beginning the learning process.

I'm currently working on an online store. One of the features that we've integrated with the shopping cart is a "quick add" field (id="cc").

Below the "quick add" field is a table that is dynamically populated with item rows. In each of these dynamically-added item rows is a "qty" text field (id="qtycart") in case the customer wants to change their qty once the item is added to the cart.

Here's what I want to do:

I want a customer to be able to add text to the "quick add" text input and click the submit button. Once the submit button is clicked, I want the focus to change from this input to the "qty" input on the newly-added row below.

Does this make sense?

Here is a simple function I put together, but I'm obviously missing something:

```
$("#cc").live("click", function(){
$("#qtycart:text:visible:last").focus();
});
```

Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: 'id' of every element should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have duplicate IDs in your DOM (qtycart). You should probably use the class name 'qtycart' instead:

```
$("#cc").live("click", function(){
    $(".qtycart:text:visible:last").focus();
});
```

The `.focus()` method does work if you're targeting the right element. Here's a little demo to simulate what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/6VZf3/2/

And here's what the W3C says about the [ID attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html):

> **id =** *name* [CS]
>
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This
>   name must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am understanding your question. Take a look at this example:

http://jsbin.com/ahusi4/2/edit

You can enter a new item and the qty input box gets the focus.

Hope this helps.

Bob